# How does the ShouldSkipPage procedure actually work in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, procedure, skip

Here's my code:

```
[Setup]
    AppName=My Program
    AppVersion=1.5
    DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
    DefaultGroupName=My Program
    UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
    Compression=lzma2
    SolidCompression=yes
    OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

    [Files]
    Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"
    Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"
    Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: isreadme

    [Icons]
    Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"

    [code]
    function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
    begin
     if PageID = 1 then 
       Result := True;
    end;
```

When I run my program in "Step Into" mode I get the next sequence of ShouldSkipPage results:
True, False, True, False. Only after that the SelectDirPage shows up. (PageID = 1 is for the WelcomePage). Can anybody explain how does the ShouldSkipPage procedure really work and why it's called like that?
Here's the list of the wizard pages:

[image: Wizard pages]

Before the SelectDirPage actually shows up the ShouldSkipPage procedure runs 4 times and returns "True", "False", "True", "False" respectively and that's exactly what I don't understand here.

Comment: Actually, this has been asked already: [ShouldSkipPage is called twice per page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40991601/850848).

Comment: I know that. I've read that post but still don't get it.
When I start my program the result is "True" for the WelcomePage. Then it's "False" like if there was a "Next" button. Then it's "True" again as if it checks if there's a page to go back to. And finally it's "False" for the SelecDirPage. But there are no "Next" and "Back" buttons on the WelcomePage.So why checking?

Comment: Add the sequence to your question and list the pages – Comments like *"Then it's "False" like if there was a "Next" button"* are rather vague. It does not tell us anything about the page you refer to.

Comment: *"returns "True", "False", "True", "False""* – Again, for **what pages**?

Comment: For me it runs two times only, with `PageID = wpSelectDir`. And actually it does not matter. It can be run as many times as Inno Setup thinks is appropriate. Is there any real problem you are solving here?

Comment: 1. True -> PageID = 1 (WelcomePage)
2. False -> PageID = 6 (SelectDirPage)
3. True -> PageID = 1 (WelcomePage)
4. False -> PageID = 6 (SelectDirPage)
So for me it runs 4 times. I don't understand why.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Inno Setup? `ShouldSkipPage` is not called for `wpWelcome` unless you have `DisableWelcomePage=no`.

Comment: I'm using the Inno Setup Compiler 5.4.2.

Comment: And anyway, you get two calls per page, as the other question says. + You should upgrade.

Comment: I would upgrade but then I won't be able to use my InnoIDE which is not supported anymore and will have to buy the Install Designer to design my forms in GUI. I can't find any similar freeware to do that.

Comment: There is this old piece of software [Inno Setup Form Designer](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=96803526635892825357) but I haven't tested if it still works with the very latest Inno Setup.

Comment: @CherryDT, Looks like it doesn't :( Do you know any freeware with similar features?